# How to disable weak HMAC Algorithms? Not found in ssh_config or sshd_config file

Tags: ssh, encryption, openssh, sshd

A vulnerability scan showed that in a Debian 10 system, insecure MAC algorithms are in use: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha1

When I do `ssh -Q mac`, I get the following results:

```
hmac-sha1
hmac-sha1-96
hmac-sha2-256
hmac-sha2-512
hmac-md5
hmac-md5-96
umac-64@openssh.com
umac-128@openssh.com
hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com
hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com
hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com
hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com
hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com
umac-64-etm@openssh.com
umac-128-etm@openssh.com
```

In the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file there is line that's commented out:

```
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com
```

There is no mention of umac-64-etm or hmac-sha1-etm in the file. In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` there is no MAC keyword at all.  How can I disable these weak HMACs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The list of supported MAC algorithms is determined by the `MACs` option, both in [`ssh_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#MACs) and in [`sshd_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#MACs). If it's absent, the default is used. If you want to change the value from the default, either edit the existing entry or add one if it isn't present. For example:

```
MACs hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com
```

Recent enough versions of OpenSSH (and [Debian 10](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/openssh-server/sshd_config.5.en.html) is recent enough) also allow a differential specification, for example to disable all short MACs and MACs based on MD5 or SHA-1:

```
MACs -*md5*,*sha1,*sha1-*,*-64,*-96
```

Note that none of the default algorithms are actually insecure. A 64-bit MAC would be very weak for offline use, but it's acceptable for network messages which are only valid within one connection which would time out before anyone can break even a 64-bit MAC. (It's a sign that they're still in the default list for OpenSSH, even though OpenSSH is very proactive about security.) MD5 and SHA1 have weaknesses that make them insecure as hashes, but the HMAC construction doesn't care about these weaknesses. I would recommend keeping at least `hmac-sha1` for interoperability with older systems unless you absolutely need to disable it for compliance (this would be about compliance and not about security).

Comment: So pretty much I have to add all the MAC algorithms from `ssh -Q mac` except the ones I don't want to both `ssh_config` and `sshd_config` ? I didn't quite understand the differential specification and where to put it. Is that supposed to exclude those MACs? Isn't it just using globbing to USE these specified MACs? Same like the above line.

I have OpenSSH_7.9p1 OpeSSL 1.1.1d 10 Sep 2019.

Comment: Nevermind, the man page of sshd that you linked says " If the specified value begins with a ‘-’ character, then the specified algorithms (including wildcards) will be removed from the default set instead of replacing them." I am however confused as to which file to put this in. `ssh_config` `sshd_config` or both.

Comment: @rocky_alpine `ssh_config` to configure the client, `sshd_config` to configure the server

Comment: Is there a way to see which algorithm is being used when I connect to this server via SSH ? Would ssh -vvv show that ?

Comment: @rocky_alpine Yes

Comment: The second option works, except for `umac-64-etm` and `umac-64`, which I still see with `ssh -Q mac` for `MACs -*md5*,*sha1,*sha1-*,*-64,*-96,*64-etm,umac-64-etm,umac-64`

Comment: This solution does not work for me.
I added both of these lines in sshd_config file:
"MACs hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com" and 
"MACs -*md5*,*sha1,*sha1-*,*-64,*-96" but stll "ssh -Q mac" shows them after restarting the service. Also "ssh -o MACs=hmac-sha1 u@h" easily connects. Any suggesions?

Comment: @Shrm I had the same issue but found a solution, so I posted a new answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Gilles answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/734247/597402) got me on the right track, but I still couldn't get the full picture. After modifying the config file, I didn't see any change in the list shown when I ran `ssh -Q mac`. I found out that it's because `ssh -Q mac` lists all MAC algorithms supported by my version of SSH, not what is currently being utilized by the server.

To get the list of what is currently being utilized by the server I used `sshd -T | egrep '^macs'`.

In my case I wanted to remove all **sha1** algorithms so I added this line `MACs -*sha1*` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

After restarting sshd with `systemctl restart sshd` and then running `sshd -T | egrep '^macs'` I could see that the **sha1** algorithms were removed from the list.