# Cannot disable weak HMAC Algorithms "umac-64" and "umac-64-etm" in sshd_config

Tags: debian, ssh, configuration

We have a security recommendation to disable weak MACs in our sshd_config.

I could disable most with this line (based on the new `-` [syntax](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/openssh-server/sshd_config.5.en.html#MACs) that is available since Debian 10):

```
MACs -*md5*,*sha1,*sha1-*,*-64,*-96,*64-etm
```

However, I somehow fail to disable `umac-64@openssh.com` and `umac-64-etm@openssh.com`.

...even if I add these explicitly to the excluded list:

```
MACs -*md5*,*sha1,*sha1-*,*-64,*-96,*64-etm,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com
```

```
ssh -Q mac
> hmac-sha1
> hmac-sha1-96
> hmac-sha2-256
> hmac-sha2-512
> hmac-md5
> hmac-md5-96
> umac-64@openssh.com <-- this
> umac-128@openssh.com
> hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com
> hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com
> hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com
> hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com
> hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
> hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com
> umac-64-etm@openssh.com  <-- and this
> umac-128-etm@openssh.com
```

Also, `sshd -T` prints my whole ssh config, and the two MACs in question are not shown there:

```
[...]
ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
macs umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
[...]
```

What is ging on?

Comment: How are you determining that they're still enabled?  `ssh -Q`?  Some other technique?

Comment: We have "CENTREON", a security inspection service, and after removing all weak HMAC successfully, these two were still listed in CENTREON. I don't know another way to check HMAC in use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable weak HMAC Algorithms? Not found in ssh\_config or sshd\_config file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/734243/how-to-disable-weak-hmac-algorithms-not-found-in-ssh-config-or-sshd-config-file)

Comment: Solved! Thank you.